# How do I solve the following scenario?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I need to create 2 comma-delimited files.  One will be in the following format:

A, 23, 10, 100, 1
A, 23, 11, 50, 1
A, 23, 12, 200, 1
A, 23, 10, 25, 2
A, 23, 11, 25, 2
A, 23, 12, 200, 2

and the other will be:

B, 23, 44, 350, 1
B, 23, 50, 250, 2

I will retrieve the initial data through a stored proc and populate a strongly-typed dataset.  The part that I am not sure how to do is parsing the data and generating the proper files.  A couple things need to happen.  The last number in each file must match, so in the example above, 1 is the last number in the first file and 1 is the last number of the first line in the second file.  In the first file, 2 is next and 2 is next in the second file.  Basically file 1 is a more drilled down look on file 2.  Most importantly, the 4th column in the second file is the sum of of all the values in the 4th column of the first file that have the same last number.  As an example, in the second file, the 4th column is 350 (because the first file has the values 100 + 50 + 200).

I was thinking I could get the data that corresponds to the more detailed file (file 1) and build file 2 on fly.  Is this there a more efficient or accurate way of doing it?  I guess I would have to keep some sort of running total and I would know when to reset the running total when I move onto an next number (this part I am not clear about), for example,  as long as I am on 1, I keep adding, but once I get to 2, I reset the total to 0, etc.

Comment: If performance is the issue, have you considered doing the `GROUP BY column5Data` aggregation of totals in your DB, rather than in your .NET client code? `Select min(col1), 'what value here?', sum(col4)
from sourceDataTable
group by col5`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do something like `secondDataSet = firstDataSet.GroupBy(x => x.Col5).Select(x => new MyType { Col4 = x.Sum(y => y.Col4), Col5 = x.Key})`?

Comment: @AVD- I am not reading a CSV, I am creating them.

Comment: @verdesmarald - No reason, I can give that a shot and let you know.  Can you explain the code?

Comment: I posted some clearer code + explanation as an answer since it doesn't really fit the format of a comment. Is that the sort of thing you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have something along the lines of this currently:

```
class MyType
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public int Col2 { get; set; }
    public int Col3 { get; set; }
    public int Col4 { get; set; }
    public int Col5 { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<MyType> firstDataSet = GetStuffFromDB();
```

From your first data set, you want to construct a second data set by grouping the entries by `Col5` and summing the values of `Col4`. You can do this easily using LINQ:

```
var secondDataSet = firstDataSet.GroupBy(entry => entry.Col5).Select
(
    group => new MyType
    {
        Col1 = "B",
        Col2 = <whatever>,
        Col3 = <whatever>,
        Col4 = group.Sum(entry => entry.Col4),
        Col5 = group.Key
    }
);
```

`GroupBy` collects the entries into groups using the given expression (so there will be a group with all the entries where `Col5` is `1`, a group with all the `2`'s, etc), and then `Select` selects a new instance of `MyType` for each group by summing the values of `Col4`.

I don't know what the values in the second and third columns are, but if they are also derived from the entries in the first data set you should be able to come up with suitable expressions in place of `<whatever>`.

Comment: I will give this a shot and let you know.

Comment: How can I do this without using LINQ?  I was about to try this, but then realized I can't use LINQ.